# Delete row from MySQL not working

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row

I'm trying to delete a row from a table in MySQL using the PHP code below. The return value from `mysql_affected_rows()` is 1. There are no errors. However, the row still exits in MySQL. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any thoughts?

```
$db = array('host'=>'127.0.0.1',  
        'user'=>'root',  
        'pass'=>'',  
        'name'=>'testdb');

// CONNECT TO THE MYSQL SERVER
$connection = mysql_connect($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass']);
if(!$connection){
    // HANDLE ERROR HERE
    die('Unable to connect to MySql server : '.mysql_error($connection));
}

// SELECT THE DATABASE SCHEMA
if(!mysql_select_db($db['name'],$connection)){
    // HANDLE ERRORS HERE
    die('Unable to connect to database : '.mysql_error($connection));
}

$result = mysql_query("delete from photos where id=".$photo_id, $connection);
echo mysql_affected_rows($connection);
```

**UPDATE**

I added the following code to the end and that solved the issue -

```
mysql_query("commit", $connection);
```

Thanks for the comments!

Comment: You should switch to mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Where does $photo_id come from?

Comment: Yeah my bet is photo_id is not set correctly

Comment: mysql_affected_rows = 1 would indicate you deleted _something_, maybe just not the `photo_id` you expected.

Comment: What about the `storage engine`? If it is `innodb` maybe needs `COMMIT` command.

Comment: try echoing the sql statement in your application so you can see exactly the information that is being passed before it is executed

Comment: $photo_id is set correctly. In fact, I changed the query to "delete from photos where id=17" (I know that id exists) and still the row did not get deleted.

Comment: @NomikOS - I added `mysql_query("commit", $con);` to the end and that did the trick! The row now is deleted from the database. Thanks!

Comment: @user1656412 Terrific! please check my answer then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applied to innodb tables as in your case.

```
mysql_query("BEGIN", $connection); 
// delete code
mysql_query("COMMIT", $connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I typically do in this cases is to enable the general_log (set global general_log_file=general.log; and set global general_log=1;) and look what arrives in there.

Then it often becomes already obvious what is the problem.

If it is not clear yet what is going on you can run these queries on the mysql console...